# How to save input value in edittext in fragment?

Tags: android

I've been trying to create a calculator app which uses Navigation Drawer. I've 6 fragments and each fragments have `EditTexts` for getting inputs from user.

But when I ran the app and type some values inside EditText (any fragments doesn't matter) and change the fragment and return to previous fragment where I entered a value before, the entered value is gone and restores default value.

How can I manage this problem?

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.testnavigation;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyListener{

     private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_gubreler, R.id.nav_sonuc, R.id.nav_hedef, R.id.nav_oranlar, R.id.nav_tankbilgileri, R.id.nav_cevirme)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }


}
```

TankBilgileriFragment

```
package com.example.testnavigation;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

public class TankBilgileriFragment extends Fragment {
    EditText tet1, tet2;
    double tet1v, tet2v;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tankbilgileri, container, false);
        tet1=(EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.tet1); tet1v=Double.parseDouble(tet1.getText().toString()); tet2=(EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.tet2); double tet2v=Double.parseDouble(tet2.getText().toString());
        return v;
    }
}
```

GubrelerFragment

```
    package com.example.testnavigation;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;

    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
    import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

    import java.text.DecimalFormat;


    public class GubrelerFragment extends Fragment{

        Button gbtnSifirla, gbtnHesapla, gbtnKaydet;
        EditText get1, get2, get3, get4, get5, get6, get7, get8, get9, get10, get11, get12, get13, get14, get15, get16;

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gubreler, container, false);


            gbtnHesapla=(Button) v.findViewById(R.id.gbtnHesapla); gbtnSifirla=(Button) v.findViewById(R.id.gbtnSifirla); gbtnKaydet=(Button) v.findViewById(R.id.gbtnKaydet);
            get1=(EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.get1);   get2=(EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.get2);   get3=(EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.get3);   get4=(EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.get4);   get5=(EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.get5);
            get6=(EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.get6);   get7=(EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.get7);   get8=(EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.get8);   get9=(EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.get9);   get10=(EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.get10);
            get11=(EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.get11); get12=(EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.get12); get13=(EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.get13); get14=(EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.get14); get15=(EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.get15);
            get16=(EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.get16);

            return v;
        }
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState!=null){
        get1.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("key1"));}
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString("key1",get1.getText().toString());
    }
    }
```

fragment_gubreler.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >
                <GridLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:columnCount="3"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/kalnit"
                        android:textSize="20sp"></TextView>
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/get1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:width="60dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:hint="L"
                        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="20sp"></EditText>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:text="L"
                        android:textSize="20sp"></TextView>:

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/potnit"
                        android:textSize="20sp"></TextView>
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/get2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:width="60dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:hint="kg"
                        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="20sp"></EditText>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:text="kg"
                        android:textSize="20sp"></TextView>:

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="string/potsul"
                        android:textSize="20sp"></TextView>
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/get3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:width="60dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:hint="kg"
                        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="20sp"></EditText>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:text="kg"
                        android:textSize="20sp"></TextView>:

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/potklr"
                        android:textSize="20sp"></TextView>
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/get4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:width="60dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:hint="kg"
                        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="20sp"></EditText>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:text="kg"
                        android:textSize="20sp"></TextView>:

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/mkp"
                        android:textSize="20sp"></TextView>
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/get5"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:width="60dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:hint="kg"
                        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="20sp"></EditText>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:text="kg"
                        android:textSize="20sp"></TextView>:

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/magnit"
                        android:textSize="20sp"></TextView>
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/get6"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:width="60dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:hint="kg"
                        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="20sp"></EditText>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:text="kg"
                        android:textSize="20sp"></TextView>:

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/magsul"
                        android:textSize="20sp"></TextView>
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/get7"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:width="60dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:hint="kg"
                        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="20sp"></EditText>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:text="kg"
                        android:textSize="20sp"></TextView>:

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/fasit"
                        android:textSize="20sp"></TextView>
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/get8"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:width="60dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:hint="L"
                        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="20sp"></EditText>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:text="kg"
                        android:textSize="20sp"></TextView>:

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Peters Professional 10-52-10:"
                        android:textSize="20sp"></TextView>
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/get9"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:width="60dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:hint="kg"
                        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="20sp"></EditText>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:text="kg"
                        android:textSize="20sp"></TextView>:

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Peters Professional 30-10-10:"
                        android:textSize="20sp"></TextView>
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/get10"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:width="60dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:hint="kg"
                        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="20sp"></EditText>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:text="kg"
                        android:textSize="20sp"></TextView>:

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/fe"
                        android:textSize="20sp"></TextView>
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/get11"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:width="60dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:hint="kg"
                        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="20sp"></EditText>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:text="kg"
                        android:textSize="20sp"></TextView>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/bor"
                        android:textSize="20sp"></TextView>
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/get12"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:width="60dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:hint="g"
                        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="20sp"></EditText>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:text="g"
                        android:textSize="20sp"></TextView>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/mn"
                        android:textSize="20sp"></TextView>
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/get13"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:width="60dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:hint="g"
                        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="20sp"></EditText>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:text="g"
                        android:textSize="20sp"></TextView>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/zn"
                        android:textSize="20sp"></TextView>
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/get14"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:width="60dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:hint="g"
                        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="20sp"></EditText>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:text="g"
                        android:textSize="20sp"></TextView>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/cu"
                        android:textSize="20sp"></TextView>
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/get15"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:width="60dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:hint="g"
                        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="20sp"></EditText>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:text="g"
                        android:textSize="20sp"></TextView>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/mo"
                        android:textSize="20sp"></TextView>
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/get16"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:width="60dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:hint="g"
                        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="20sp"></EditText>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:text="g"
                        android:textSize="20sp"></TextView> </GridLayout>  </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/gbtnSifirla"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/sfr"></Button>
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/gbtnHesapla"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/hesap"></Button>
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/gbtnKaydet"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/kaydet"></Button>  </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Frist of all, where is your code? Without code helping is nearly impossible. Second When you switch between fragments the last current fragment gets destroyed and created new when you return. As this implies all values are gone... You need to store this values when the fragment gets destroyed and get them when the fragment gets recreated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed my problem with SharedPreferences. I added a button in my Fragment and onClick method to save values with SharedPreferences and restored values inside onCreateView (before return v;) so even I close the app or change any other fragment values still remain.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about "saveInstance"

```java
@Override public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
{ super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
 outState.putString("dataGotFromServer", dataGotFromServer); 
} 

@Override public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 { super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState); 
dataGotFromServer = savedInstanceState.getString("dataGotFromServer"); 
}
```

Comment: thanks for the info. looks like yes i need to learn about "saveInstance". will look on it.

Comment: I tried what you said. I also tried using saveInstanceState inside onCreateView but still I can't do what I want. Propably I'm doing something wrong. When I run the app and type value like 200 inside EditText (for a test I only did that think for the first EditText) and change the fragment and return to previous fragment that value is gone.